# I'm adding a record which contains a price, £9.50, and it's being rounded up/down?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple insert record to add an item to a recordset. The data field for price is set to decimal and when the price field is sent e.g. 9.50 it appears in the database as 9.00. Why?

Here's the code from the php insert statement

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO buying (`user`, items, price) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['user'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['items'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['price'], "int"));
```

Comment: @rich also what is type of database field?
Is is (FLOAT or DOUBLE PRECISION)

Comment: @Pradeep, it is decimal.

Comment: if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO buying (`user`, items, price) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['user'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['items'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['price'], "int"));

Comment: @Rich: Don't write it here. Include it, formatted, in your question.

Comment: sorry guys, I'll add the code to the question, my bad !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html):

> The declaration syntax for a `DECIMAL` column is `DECIMAL(M,D)`.

So, what did you specify for `D`? Sounds like perhaps `0`.

---

### Edit

I don't know what `GetSQLValueString` is, but you wrote `GetSQLValueString($_POST['items'], "int")` which seems to imply that you're creating an *integer*, no?

If it's [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458180/php-getsqlvaluestring-function), I think you clearly meant `GetSQLValueString($_POST['items'], "double")`.